# Why can't I pass these arguments in Remix?

Tags: arguments, remix, openzeppelin

I'm trying to deploy [OpenZeppelin PaymentSplitter.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v2.0.0/contracts/payment/PaymentSplitter.sol) but I'm getting the following error in Remix:

```
creation of PaymentSplitter errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: expected array value (arg="", coderType="array", type="string", value="0x075e829D8420786210b728df8D75CE2E5375A57a")
```

I've tried passing:

```
"0x075e829D8420786210b728df8D75CE2E5375A57a",10 (I believe this should the correct way)
"0x075e829D8420786210b728df8D75CE2E5375A57a", 10    
0x075e829D8420786210b728df8D75CE2E5375A57a,10 
"0x075e829D8420786210b728df8D75CE2E5375A57a", "10"
```

but each one produces the same error.

Can anyone shed any light on why this isn't working, please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The parameters expected are in array, so if you wanna pass those above values, pass like this:

```
[0x075e829D8420786210b728df8D75CE2E5375A57a], [10]
```

Hope it helps!